# Linking Java Invocation API on Windows with CMAKE

Tags: java, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to get familiar with C++/CMake and linking on Windows by starting a JVM with the Java Invocation API. Unfortunately, I'm having some problems understanding how linking works on Windows. I'm using CLion with Visual Studio 2019 installed.

I'm having OpenJDK 13 installed at `C:/dev/Java/jdk-13.0.2` where my `JAVA_HOME` is pointed to.

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(cppjni)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(JNI REQUIRED)

message("jni libraries ${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
add_executable(cppjni main.cpp MyJvm.cpp MyJvm.h)
target_include_directories(cppjni PUBLIC ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(cppjni ${JNI_LIBRARIES})
```

The MyJVM class is just a simple wrapper around the JNI interface, as specified in the tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html.

Unfortunately, whenever I start this in Clion, I get a

```
C:\dev\Workspace\cppjni\cmake-build-debug\cppjni.exe

Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

I *think* this is because the linking does not correctly work. If I set the working directory to
`C:\dev\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\server`, the application starts.

The FindJNI script prints this, if I run cmake manually in Powershell:

```
-- Found JNI: C:/dev/Java/jdk-13.0.2/lib/jawt.lib
jni libraries C:/dev/Java/jdk-13.0.2/lib/jawt.lib;C:/dev/Java/jdk-13.0.2/lib/jvm.lib
```

As far as I understand, these are the static libraries of the JVM. They should then be included into the final binary, right? Or do I have to ship the jvm.dll with my application whenver I run it?

Also, the jvm.dll is about 12 mb in size, but the jvm.lib is only 977 kb. This can't be the same JVM, right? But why does FindJNI not find the jvm.dll?

Thanks!

Comment: "As far as I understand, these are the static libraries of the JVM." - No, a `.lib` file could denote an **import file**, corresponding to the dynamic library (`.dll`). According to the error code you got, this is actually your case.